# display grid as default in list/grid view switcher

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
   http://jsfiddle.net/akarun/LJf9p/
```

I need this jsfiddle code to implement in my web page. The problem is I don't know how to make the grid appear as default. In this demo the list is displayed as default. I need to have the grid displayed as default, and then when I press list view, to be displayed as a list.

```js
$('button').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('grid')) {
        $('#container ul').removeClass('list').addClass('grid');
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('list')) {
        $('#container ul').removeClass('grid').addClass('list');
    }
});
```

```css
#container ul { list-style: none; }
#container .buttons { margin-bottom: 20px; }

#container .list li { width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; }

#container .grid li { float: left; width: 20%; height: 50px; border-right: 1px dotted #CCC; border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC; padding: 20px; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="grid">Grid View</button>
        <button class="list">List View</button>
    </div>
    
    <ul class="list">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 7</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: <ul class="list"> Change the class here to grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in following way:

http://jsfiddle.net/LJf9p/851/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#container ul').addClass('grid');

  $('button').click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('grid')) {
      $('#container ul').removeClass('list').addClass('grid');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('list')) {
      $('#container ul').removeClass('grid').addClass('list');
    }
  });

})
```

On `document` ready event just set the `grid` class to `$('#container ul')` element

Comment: @vijayP Good one. But i think your solution is not a proper way of achieving it. why we need to  write an extra script to do so. Instead just change the default class name from list to grid.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar - totally agree with you. I am not that much efficient in HTML and CSS...`:)`!

Answer (score 1):

By default u have `class="List"` in your `HTML` change it as `class="grid"`